# find innerhtml in html tag excluding that tag using php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Using preg_match_all(), I want to match something like:

```
"<table class='list2'><tr><th>States</th><th width='55' class='view'>Localities</th></tr></table>"
```

This is exactly the string I'm trying to extract data from, including the brackets, quotes, angle-brackets etc...

I want "th" innerhtml using preg_match_all().

I am use this expression

```
(?=<th[^>]*>)(.*?)(?=<\/th>)
```

it will give me

```
"<th>States" and "<th width='55' class='view'>Localities"
```

but I want only "States" and "Localities".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match states and Localities. `\K` is used to cutdown the previously matched strings.

```
<th.*?>\K[^<]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yQ9qP5/3)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$data = "\"<table class='list2'><tr><th>States</th><th width='55' class='view'>Localities</th></tr></table>\"";
$regex =  '~<th.*?>\K[^<]*~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "States"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Localities"
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `<th.*?>` Matches `<th` upto the first occurrence of  `>`
- `\K` Previously matched characters are discarded.
- `[^<]*` Matches any character not of `<` zero or more times.